# Maximum number of items returned in GCS Objects#list request

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

If I didn't specify the [maxResults](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) query parameter and I have a bucket with huge number of objects. Will all objects be returned in a single request? if not, how many will be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A limited number of results will come back in a single response - typically 1000. To list the entire bucket, you need to use markers.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#getbucket documents how listing buckets works, using the XML API. At the end of that section it notes the max # objects returned per request is 1000.

Comment: is it hidden or something? :) Found it: "Google Cloud Storage does not return lists longer than 1,000 objects.", thanks!